# Change notifications on .NET windows application

Tags: .net, message-queue, windows

We have a .NET 2.0 windows application used by around 50 users. Main UI element in the application is an interative Gantt Chart (iLOG Gantt 3.0). When one user makes a change on the Gantt chart, we like the change to be updated on all the clients.

Can someone suggest how can we implement this effectively?

Solutions candidates so far are

- Polling the DB server for changes from each connectd node(!!)
- Message queue based solutions(publish-subscribe model)

Do we have any other choices?

Comment: Some sort of message queue (for example MSMQ even if it's too much for such simple task, you may implement a SIMPLE notification server on the same machine where DB is). Definitely.

Answer (score 1):

50 users is a small number. Database polling wouldn't have any significant impact if done properly, and it's the simplest way that won't require any extra parts to your architecture.

If you're afraid of scalability issues, a relatively simple alternative could be to have a little TCP or UDP socket based service running on the database server, to which the clients would connect. It would then poll the database regularly and send a signal to any connected clients whenever changes happen.